# Set selected value of select menus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-init

I have three select menu that bind to each other and want to set selected value of two select menus. Value that I want to set comes with scope. I try ng-init but that didn't work. Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/foFjixSEyXtoEeP9uSHP?p=info)

```
<select ng-init="selManga=direk" ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangas">
    <option value="">Select a Manga</option>
</select>

<select ng-init="selChapter=bacanak" ng-show="selManga" class="browser-default" ng-model="selChapter" ng-options="+idx as chapter.klasor for (idx, chapter) in selManga.randomword">
    <option value="">Chapter</option>
</select>

<select ng-show="selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol" class="browser-default" ng-model="selPage" ng-options="+idx as (+idx + 1) for (idx, page) in selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol">
    <option value="">Page</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {
$scope.direk = $stateParams.seri;
$scope.bacanak = $stateParams.klasor;

MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen) {
    $scope.mangas = loHemen;
});
$scope.next = function (manga, chapter, page) {
    var nextPage = page + 1;
    if (angular.isDefined(manga.randomword[chapter].yol[nextPage])) {
        $scope.selPage = nextPage;
    } else if (angular.isDefined(manga.randomword[chapter + 1])) {
        $scope.selChapter = chapter + 1;
        $scope.selPage = 0;
    }
}
})
```

Comment: You want to set the default values of the dropdowns ?

Comment: @George Bora No. Set the selected ones. Like this: [MangaYurdu](http://mangayurdu.com/oku/One_Piece/803)

Comment: Your question is not clear..Please ask properly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Sarjan Desai I want to set selected values of select menus. Data comes from links. For example here is link `http://mangayurdu.com/oku/Naruto/300`. I want to set selected value of first select menu to `Naruto` and selected value of second select menu `300`. Naruto and 300 comes with $stateParams and the then $scope.

Comment: the code in your fiddle is not what you have here, so which one is it?

Comment: @Nasuh I got it now, what you're saying you want to extract the manga/chapter/page from the url,  Do you also want using the dropdowns to change the url ?

Comment: @George Bora Yes if that possible it would be nice that dropdown changes the url. I didnt thought of that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the values for the manga,chapter and page from the url you should use the `$routeParams` object, which your module should include `ngRoute`.

I've prepared an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5TYBQovtHeuocaOUyroZ?p=preview) it might not be obvious but if you download the code and run it in your own browser you can access routes like `Manga/Naruto/ch/100` from the url bar.

Once you've restructured your application to use routes and routeParams, in my example I directly bind the chapter and page I get from the url to the view but if you bind them to the models of your dropdowns the dropdowns will update.

```
$scope.params = $routeParams;
$scope.selManga = $scope.params.bookId
```

This does not update the url as you select from the dropdown.

Comment: Here sir, I finally manage the create plunk. Could you look at it please? [http://plnkr.co/edit/foFjixSEyXtoEeP9uSHP?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/foFjixSEyXtoEeP9uSHP?p=info)

Comment: @Nasuh I downloaded the plunkr and it worked for me, congratulations, do you want to add something more ? ps: don't call me sir :)) I'm not that old

Comment: Dont understand you will help or not?

Comment: @Nasuh I've looked more closely at your plunker, and I'm changing it a little, where do you set the options for the manga dropdown ?

Comment: In the `app.js` file. `MyCtrl`.

Comment: @Nasuh I managed to fix some problems and now the manga is selected, selecting the chapter will be a bit more tricky, https://gist.github.com/GBora/3ef7af82e4cc7fbf6e62

Comment: Okay thank you. I got it worked but there is much to be done.:)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have assign `direk` and `bacanak` value more than one times which can cause issue. Set `variable` property only once.

```
$scope.direk = $stateParams.seri;
$scope.bacanak = $stateParams.klasor;

$scope.direk = $stateParams.xy;   //Remove if not required
$scope.bacanak = $stateParams.xz; //Remove if not required
```

Set `selManga` value from `$stateParams` instead of setting it to `direk`

```
$scope.selManga = $stateParams.seri;  // Set selManga from $stateParams
$scope.selChapter = $stateParams.klasor;  // Set selChapter from $stateParams
```

The reason why `ng-init="selManga=direk"` not work is because Syntax error: `ng-init="selManga=direk"` should be `ng-init="selManga='direk'"` **but** after making syntax correct, `dropdown` will not set because of `ng-repeat`. `ng-init` set value to model but at time of setting value `ng-repeat` doesn't complete setting value for options so `selManga` set from ng-init not update option to dropdown.